# Cookie to Remember and Redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

This might be a complex question but what I need to do is real similar to the country select pages you used to see when you went to a manufacturer's site – the ones that asked you where you were from and then after selecting you were sent to the appropriate site, say the US version or Spanish version. I've seen these done with pop-ups or shadowboxes which is preferred. So...

1. When you go to our homepage a pop-up (or better yet, a shadow-box) comes up after two seconds
2. The user is offered a graphic and/or text link to go to site A or site B
3. The user selects the right site for them and is sent to it
4. Cookie(s) are left with the user so 
   A.  They never see the choice box again as long as the cookie is there.
   B.  They are always redirected to their correct choice when they hit the page.

In my research it looks like you can do one but not both. What do you think?

Comment: I think you have a list of requirements, what kind of advice do you want?  Not sure what your asking.

Comment: "you can do one but not both" -- not sure what is "both". What you described is absolutely possible, and a pretty basic use of cookies.

Comment: `it looks like you can do one but not both` one (or both) of which two options?

Comment: What happens if cookies are disabled? You may see that as a minority, but on our website we had quite a large number of users who didn't have cookies and therefore would never get to view our site. I think the best solution is to not force the user to choose a country or language. Make it default to something, then give them the option somewhere on the page to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly what you'll need in order to carry out each step

```
function redirectPopup(){
 /*Do your popup stuff*/
}

document.onload = function(){

    /*set timer to call your popup renderer*/
    setTimeout(redirectPopup,2000)
}
```

With the above you have several options for the popup, I'd recommend one of the following

-Have the popup included in the response text from the site visit with its visibility set to hidden. Then have your redirectPopup function change the style properties to show the popup - disable every thing else.
-Have the redirectPopup function generate the entire popup window.

As for the cookie you can use the setcookie function http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php that can be used to automatically redirect the user on site visit. For example:

```
/*Server request with $_GET redirectTo property*/
if(isset($_GET['redirectTo']))
    setcookie('redirectTo', $_GET['redirectTo'], time() + 86400 * 14);

/*Check if the redirectTo cookie exists, redirect if true*/
if(isset($_COOKIE['redirectTo']))
    header("location:". $_COOKIE['redirectTo']);

/*Do your initial, no redirect stuff here*/
....
```

In the above example when a user visits the site the server first checks to see if they've selected a redirect option; it has been assumed that when the user selects a redirect option that the destination url is the same as the site with the inclusion of a GET parameter 'redirectTo'.  If a value is found for this parameter it is assumed that the user must have visited the site in order to see the redirect options and their redirect cookie is set.

The second section checks to see if the cookie is set and redirects the user if it is. In this example I've simply passed the cookie value to the header function, in practice it will be more practical to handle this in a slightly more involved manner.

The setcookie method doesn't requires a finite time period is passed to it and therefore you can't set a perpetual cookie, you can however set it with a ridiculous retention period. Finally cookies are only accessible by a user from the machine and browser which they are using at the time, redirecting indiscriminate of time and location can't be achieved without some form of user logging.

Kevin B makes a good point about users not always having cookies enabled. With that in mind the first line section of the php code might be edited to the following for handling such occasions.

```
/*Server request with $_GET redirectTo property*/
if(isset($_GET['redirectTo']))

    /*Where setting a cookie fails*/
    if(! setcookie('redirectTo', $_GET['redirectTo'], time() + 86400 * 14))
        header("location:" $_GET['redirectTo']);
```

As with the previous the redirect might benefit from being a bit more involved but using this method will force the redirect when cookies aren't available.

Comment: Huge thanks. This is a great lead and I will use it to point me in the right direction -- really appreciate it Oliver.

Comment: Also sorry for not making things clear on my posting - this is my first here and was rookie about it. Will be more specific next time. Kevin I am with you, this is not good for usability or SEO. I would much rather have it on the site but unfortunately the client will have is way despite my protest... Thanks again all.